# Python Boto AWS Remove VPC Security Group Rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-vpc

I'm currently automating the build of an AWS VPC but wish to remove the default rules added to the security group created with the VPC. I can view security group rules like so:

`for security_group in vpc_connection.get_all_security_groups():
     for rule in vpc_security_group.rules:
         print dir(rule)`

I'd be grateful if anyone could tell me or give me an example of how to remove the default rules from the VPC.

From the API documentation I can see that there are a few methods such as:

`boto.ec2.connection.revoke_security_group()`

However I am not clear on what needs to be passed in as arguments if this is indeed the correct method.

Many thanks

H

Comment: Note that there is currently a newer version of boto in development (https://github.com/boto/boto3).

Answer (score 6):

I figured this out in the end:

```
for rule in vpc_security_group.rules:
    for grant in rule.grants:
        ec2_connection.revoke_security_group(group_id=vpc_security_group.id, ip_protocol=rule.ip_protocol, from_port=rule.from_port, to_port=rule.to_port, src_security_group_group_id=grant.group_id, cidr_ip=grant.cidr_ip)

for rule in vpc_security_group.rules_egress:
    for grant in rule.grants:
        ec2_connection.revoke_security_group_egress(vpc_security_group.id, rule.ip_protocol, rule.from_port, rule.to_port, grant.group_id, grant.cidr_ip)
```

Comment: Did this actually work? I've found that this approach doesn't remove all the items. I had better luck copying the lists. i.e. for rule in list(vpc_security_group.rules): for grant in list(rule.grants): - but this is still not catching all the grants...

Comment: It removes the initial rules on a VPC security group for me. I haven't tested whether it removes all rules if others are added subsequently is all I can say at the moment.

Comment: Upon closer examination I realized that your code doesn't have the problem. I was useing vpc_security_gropu.revoke - which has a bug. It attempts to update the local list of rules inside the security_group. Somehow this gets confused when looping over the grants.

Comment: Thank you this worked for me, sadly the boto documentation (while fantastic) is missing some key pieces and examples..

Answer (score 0):

I used some of your logic above to craft a couple python scripts that will remove a security group whether it is in ec2-classic or VPC (assuming ingress rules only).  There are a couple special cases, such as your SG to be deleted is referenced in an ingress rule in another SG.  Another special case is referencing the AWS default SG for ELB in EC2-classic.  Both are handled gracefully, and the scripts can be found here: https://gist.github.com/arpcefxl/2acd7d873b95dbebcd42